# Add static item to RadComboBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik

I have a set of two cascading `RadComboBoxes` - when one is set, the other populates.  The second combobox has its `ItemSource` set to a `CompositeCollection` that's binding to an `ObservableCollection` in the viewmodel.

I'm attempting to add a static value to the list.  The idea is that the CompositeCollection can change, but there should always be one static `ComboBoxItem` available named *Other*.

CustomerContact.cs:

```
public class CustomerContact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

CustomerContactSource:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="CustomerContactSource" Source="{Binding CustomerSite.CustomerContacts}">
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Name"/>
    </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

OtherCustomerContact:

```
public CustomerContact OtherCustomerContactItem => new CustomerContact
{
    Name = "Other", 
    Email = string.Empty, 
    PhoneNumber = string.Empty 
};
```

Xaml page:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemTemplate}"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding CustomerContact}"                                                     
                     Text="{Binding Source=CustomerContact, Path=Name}">
    <telerik:RadComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource CustomerContactSource}}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source=OtherCustomerContactItem, Path=Name}"/>                                                          
        </CompositeCollection>                                   
    </telerik:RadComboBox.ItemsSource>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

I keep getting an error stating that no converter can be found for TextBlock to CustomerContact.  What am I doing wrong?  The RadComboBox has an ItemSource that's a list of `CustomerContact` and a single, unchanging item that's *also* of type `CustomerContact`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: post your viewmodel code.. or where your OtherCustomerContactItem object exists.. I think it is not able to bind the OtherCustomerContactItem correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The RadComboBox has an ItemSource that's a list of CustomerContact and
>   a single, unchanging item that's also of type CustomerContact.

That last part doesn't hold. You're wrapping the item in a TextBlock and that's 
the type XAML sees. Giving an error due to lack of TypeConverter.

You could wrap the item:

- in a Collection(Container) of its own.
- in a RadComboBoxItem in the lines of what is 
  done [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742405(v=vs.110).aspx) for a ListBox.